# MVC redirect to a view without a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hopefully should be a simple one. I have created a generic error view that I want to show when a exception occurs inside action methods across the site. I have created a partial page where all the navigation lives so therefore I do not need a controller on this view, so how do I redirect to it from a action method inside a controller?

Something like this...

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Test(VM viewModel)
 { 
     try
     {
         // posting info to the server...
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        //Log exception..

        //show an error view, however no action method so how do I redirect?
        return RedirectTo ??? ("Error");
     }
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: MVC works using controllers - as far as I know you need a controller in order to display a view, is there any reason you can't just create an `ErrorController`?

Comment: Is this in a separate folder from your other views?

Comment: Yeah I'm being stupid and trying to be lazy, its just I have no model for this view so I dont really want or require a controller. but yeah, the time it took to write this post would be enough to create the controller...cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `return View()`

***This tells MVC to generate HTML to be displayed for the specified view and sends it to the browser. This acts like as `Server.Transfer()` in Asp.Net WebForm***.

```
     {
       //Log exception..    
        //show an error view, however no action method so how do I redirect?
        return View("your view path");
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need to create a controller and a route for your error view.

An alternative approach is to make your error view a plain html page and just redirect to it like this:

```
return Redirect("~/error.html");
```

I found this guide to be very useful when setting up custom errors on other MVC applications: http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

Hope this helps.

Comment: No prob. The benefit of using the strategy in that post is that all of your errors will be automatically handled by the framework and IIS. No custom code is necessary and you can easily test your error pages by changing a few lines in your Web.config :)