# How to find view name for action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For instance this action

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        // some code here
        return View();
    }
}
```

How do we know the view name for the SomeAction()?

Comment: by convention: SomeAction :)

Comment: If you don't specify the view name as an argument to the `View(string viewName)` method, the `ViewEngine` will use the action name.

Comment: just right click on action name and select go to view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237029/mvc-redirect-to-a-view-without-a-controller/26237096#26237096